# Internet disconnects after a few minutes after starting Windows 10

Tags: networking, internet, windows-10-preview

Today I was connected to internet provider, which provides 100 Mbit/s Ethernet. The connection process is very simple. I just plug RJ-45 to my laptop, and everythink has worked. My provider has DHCP, so I got some DNS and other typical stuff automatically. I have one problem.

Internet works pretty good for 5 minutes after starting Windows 10. Then I see yellow sign in tray and "No network access - unidentified network".

[image]

[image]

Note, that this internet provider is not first for this laptop. In past (then I have Windows 7), I used other provider, Everything was OK.

[image]

Comment: Although I do not have an answer to this, some observations I made: - I experience the same issue after upgrading to build 10162. On build 10130, the issue did not occur for me. After reverting to 10130, the issue is also gone.
- After the upgrade, my adapter was not working at all. In the [configuration](http://res1.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/windows%207/main/25e7e385-9327-4f7d-aab0-afa5aaf952ba_49.jpg), nearly all "features" were turned off (like TCP/IPv4 & 6). Only after switching these on and rebooting, the behavior as you describe happened to me.
- My ethernet adapter is also called

Comment: it is amazing. I think, that you are absolutely right. If I download some big file, I get trouble simultaneously. On the other hand, if I just just turn on my laptop, internet will work correctly for long time (1-2 hour, may be).
I had 10130 build, when I discovered the problem. Then I update to 10162, and the problem persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix it. I was using an old driver from Jan. 2013, though Windows Update did not find any new  version. I installed [this](https://www.broadcom.com/support/?gid=12) (NetLink® 57xx (x64) - 15.6.0.10), which is from July 2013. After that, the connection is not lost anymore.

Comment: my driver is Jan. 2013 too. I try to reinstall driver, Thank you.

Comment: @mnkypetem, it seems, that it works. Thank you!

Comment: Worked also for Realtek PCIe GBE controller on ASUS notebook.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED - finally found the solution. For anyone else with this issue disabling the following settings should work:

Go to Device Manager, network adapters, and find the ethernet one.

- right-click for properties - advanced ...power management
- Disable Energy-efficient ethernet (and or green energy) and Wake on magic packet.

https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Ethernet-wired-connection-keeps-disconnecting/td-p/6216566